# Robust LMM or Random Forest?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, random-forest, robust

I have non-normally distributed, heteroscedacic and autocorrelated data. To overcome these issues I would like to use robust linear mixed models with the robustlmm package in R or random forest regression. Which do you think is better suited?
My continuous response is yield [dt/ha] and my fixed effect predictor variables are weed coverage [%, continuous], soil moisture content [%, continuous], distance [categorical] and treatment[categorical]. Date, Site and Plot shall be modeled as random effects. I am quite new to statistics, so short and easy answers with as less math as possible are highly appreciated. :) Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do with this model and why? Are you trying to understand experimental data/infer effects of some treatment? Is this observational data and you want to infer causal effects of treatment? Or do you wish to predict future crop-yields (a short time into the future? Next year? Next 5 years?)? Why is the data autocorrelated (e.g. time series of yields for each year of the same plots)?

Comment: Hey Björn, thanks for your answer! So basically I want to find out which predictors have a significant influence on the response. I dont want to any predictions. I used the check_autocorrelation() function from the performance-package and it said, that the residuals seem to be autocorrelated.

Comment: What's the nature of the data though? Experimental? Why the auto correlation (time series?)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by nature of the data, but I measured soil moisture content every two weeks, five times in total and weed coverage one time in the end of the experiment. I am not really sure why there is auto correlation.. Thank you!

Comment: In that case, auto-correlation over time makes sense to me. I don't think RF will lend itself very easily towards getting the kind of interpretation you seem to want out of this data. Some kind of mixed model certainly sounds more logical. Transforming the response variable (e.g. log-transformation for yield, if it's always positive) may be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know a good source where I can find some real life examples on how to use GLMM and how to present and visualize the most important estimates and parameters?